# meaning of 'yield perpetual dickaround'

Tags: meaning

> A: They going to give you a new partner?
>
> B: How would I know? No one tells
> you anything. It’s the N.Y.P.D.
>
> A: I know, right? Never Yielding
> perpetual Dickaround.

what does it mean?
They(NYPD) never make a decision that wastes time?

Comment: I suspect it's meant as two phrases - something like 'obstinate and in a perpetual muddle'.

Comment: The split looks to me as NY, PD

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense to me.

Comment: Look up *dick around* (US): to meddle with or manipulate (someone); to treat (someone) unfairly.

Comment: No, it's not POB.

Comment: This isn't a common idiom, it's just a humorous expansion of the NYPD acronym (which normally stands for New York Police Department).